# What is the best way to recursively copy contents in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion

What is the best way to recursively copy a folder's content into another folder using C# and ASP.NET?

Comment: By "best", do you mean the safest, quickest, or maybe the method that uses the least memory?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well you can try this

```
DirectoryInfo sourcedinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\source");
DirectoryInfo destinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\destination");
copy.CopyAll(sourcedinfo, destinfo);
```

and this is the method that do all the work:

```
public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    try
    {
        //check if the target directory exists
        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }

        //copy all the files into the new directory

        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
        }


        //copy all the sub directories using recursion

        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceDir, nextTargetDir);
        }
        //success here
    }
    catch (IOException ie)
    {
        //handle it here
    }
}
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Great code there is one thing i would change: 
//check if the target directory exists
    if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
    }
you can just you the DirectoryInfo object you already have:
    if (!target.Exists)
    {
         target.Create();                    
    }

Comment: Worked OK for me with no changes.

Comment: one a few occasions i've had `target.Exists` not work correctly where `Directory.Exists(target.FullName)` did...

Comment: I have to copy files having size in GBs. Will this solution in answer work for me?

Answer (score 19):

Just use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory` in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` assembly.

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source, destination);
```

Comment: sounds useful. how came that Directory class doesn't have this method??

Answer (score 6):

You can use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to recursively search down folders, you just need to create the directories before you copy...

```
// string source, destination; - folder paths 
int pathLen = source.Length + 1;

foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string subPath = dirPath.Substring(pathLen);
    string newpath = Path.Combine(destination, subPath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath );
}

foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string subPath = filePath.Substring(pathLen);
    string newpath = Path.Combine(destination, subPath);
    File.Copy(filePath, newpath);
}
```

Comment: brilliant! the only tweak i had to do is int pathLen = source.Length + 1