# What is the best way to copy a folder and all subfolders and files using c#

Tags: c#

I need to copy a Folder from one drive to a removable Hard disk.
The Folder which needs to be copied will have many sub folders and files in it.
The input will be Source Path and Target Path.

Like..

Source Path : "C:\SourceFolder"

Target Path : "E:\"

After copying is done, i shud be able to see the folder "SourceFolder" in my E: drive.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627504/what-is-the-best-way-to-recursively-copy-contents-in-c

Comment: Hm, well now people are just copying from the other questions, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private static bool CopyDirectory(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath, bool overwriteexisting)
        {
            bool ret = true;
            try
            {
                SourcePath = SourcePath.EndsWith(@"\") ? SourcePath : SourcePath + @"\";
                DestinationPath = DestinationPath.EndsWith(@"\") ? DestinationPath : DestinationPath + @"\";

                if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath))
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(DestinationPath) == false)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);

                    foreach (string fls in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath))
                    {
                        FileInfo flinfo = new FileInfo(fls);
                        flinfo.CopyTo(DestinationPath + flinfo.Name, overwriteexisting);
                    }
                    foreach (string drs in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath))
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo drinfo = new DirectoryInfo(drs);
                        if (CopyDirectory(drs, DestinationPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexisting) == false)
                            ret = false;
                    }
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DI_Target + "//Database");
                }
                else
                {
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: what         Directory.CreateDirectory(DI_Target + "//Database"); is

Answer (score 12):

I think this is it.

```
public static void CopyFolder(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target) {
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in source.GetDirectories())
        CopyFolder(dir, target.CreateSubdirectory(dir.Name));
    foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name));
}
```

Comment: It have permission problem. Can you overcome it ?

Answer (score 8):

Found this at [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/257490-How-Copy-directories-in-C/). Haven't tried it myself.

```
public static class DirectoryInfoExtensions
{
    // Copies all files from one directory to another.
    public static void CopyTo(this DirectoryInfo source, 
            string destDirectory, bool recursive)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (destDirectory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destDirectory");
        // If the source doesn't exist, we have to throw an exception.
        if (!source.Exists)
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory not found: " + source.FullName);
        // Compile the target.
        DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(destDirectory);
        // If the target doesn't exist, we create it.
        if (!target.Exists)
            target.Create();
        // Get all files and copy them over.
        foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
        {
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name), true);
        }
        // Return if no recursive call is required.
        if (!recursive)
            return;
        // Do the same for all sub directories.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            CopyTo(directory, 
                Path.Combine(target.FullName, directory.Name), recursive);
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage looks like this:

```
var source = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\users\chris\desktop");
source.CopyTo(@"C:\users\chris\desktop_backup", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

**How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree (C# Programming Guide)**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Comment: Just fyi, The code on that page leaves out the part he really needs. Note the comment, *To recursively iterate through all subfolders under the current directory, see "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree."*

Answer (score 1):

for googlers: in pure win32/C++, use [SHCreateDirectoryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131(VS.85).aspx)

```
inline void EnsureDirExists(const std::wstring& fullDirPath)
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    const SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *psa = NULL;
    int retval = SHCreateDirectoryEx(hwnd, fullDirPath.c_str(), psa);
    if (retval == ERROR_SUCCESS || retval == ERROR_FILE_EXISTS || retval == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        return; //success

    throw boost::str(boost::wformat(L"Error accessing directory path: %1%; win32 error code: %2%") 
        % fullDirPath
        % boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(retval));

    //TODO *djg* must do error handling here, this can fail for permissions and that sort of thing
}
```

Comment: Wasn't this question about C#? Not that I am complaining (still upvoted). Very useful method, jsut a bit out of context here

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use something like [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)?

It has a mirroring option where the directory structure of source is copied as-is inot te destination. There are various command line options. Might save you the effort to replicate the features in your code.

Comment: Because RoboCopy is an external application. It's always better to try doing things natively in code first (if it's not too complicated to do so), before resorting to shelling out to another program to do them.

Answer (score -1):

And here is a different take on the problem:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
  new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"XCOPY C:\folder D:\Backup\folder /i");
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process copyFolders = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
copyFolders.WaitForExit();
```