# How to copy files in subdirectory?

Tags: c#

How to modify the code to copy and files in subdirectoryes of tempDownloadFolder?

```
private void moveFiles()
{
   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempDownloadFolder);
   FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

   foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
   {
       if (fi.Name != downloadFile)
        File.Copy(tempDownloadFolder + fi.Name, destinationFolder + fi.Name, true);
   }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146021/copy-all-files-in-directory
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742300/what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-folder-and-all-subfolders-and-files-using-c-sharp

Comment: from MSDN "How to: Copy Directories" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx

Comment: Why is the method now called `moveFiles`? It doesn't move files!

Comment: move becouse overwrite old files, then another method delete tempDownloadFolder

Comment: Still it doesn't move files if the old files are deleted from another method. `moveFiles` could be a method that calls `copyFiles` *and* `deleteFiles`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a recursive search.

very rough example:

```
    private void copyFiles(string filePath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            // test if fi is a directory
            // if so call copyFiles(fi.FullName) again
            // else execute the following
            if (fi.Name != downloadFile) File.Copy(filePath+ fi.Name, destinationFolder + fi.Name, true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is roughly what I was going to suggest: +1.

Comment: fi will never be a directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want files of all subdirectories use the `SearchOption` parameter:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempDownloadFolder);
di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
   if (fi.Name != downloadFile)
   File.Copy(tempDownloadFolder + fi.Name, destinationFolder + fi.Name, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the File.Copy line by

```
File.Copy(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fi.Name), true);
```

Comment: I have tryed all solutions, but still can't copy subfolders

Comment: The question is what exactly you want to do: Copy files from a certain subdirectory to another (existing) subdirectory? This can be done by this snippet. Or do you want to copy all files recursively? Then, of course, you would have to use di.GetDirectories() to query for subfolders, create this as a subdirectory of the destination folder and only then start copying files. Copying files can be done by recursively calling the copy method.

Comment: I want to copy all content of current directory +subdirectories. Lilke xcopy/e command

Comment: Well, as told before, you have to create all subdirectories (by `Directory.CreateDirectory`) before you want to copy there.

Comment: Tryed to create subdirs manualy,but they still are empty. Method copies files only in root directory.

Comment: You need to search files recursively and build the correct destination path. Let the debugger show you paths if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Just find working solution here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3210/Function-to-copy-a-directory-to-another-place-noth?msg=4571843#xx4571843xx