# ASP.NET C# Copy Directory with SubDirectories with System.IO

Tags: c#, asp.net, copy, .net, subdirectory

I need to copy a whole directory C:\X to C:\Y\X, and I need the sub-folders to be copied as well.
Is there any way to do it with the System.IO.File\Directory namespaces ?
Thanks for all helpers!

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627504/what-is-the-best-way-to-recursively-copy-contents-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This class will copy or move a folder, without recursive calls.
The methods is using their own stacks to handle recursion, this is to avoid **StackOverflowException**.

```
public static class CopyFolder
{
    public static void CopyDirectory(string source, string target)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Folders>();
        stack.Push(new Folders(source, target));

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var folders = stack.Pop();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folders.Target);
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folders.Source, "*.*"))
            {
                string targetFile = Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(file));
                if (File.Exists(targetFile)) File.Delete(targetFile);
                File.Copy(file, targetFile);
            }

            foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folders.Source))
            {
                stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void MoveDirectory(string source, string target)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Folders>();
        stack.Push(new Folders(source, target));

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var folders = stack.Pop();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folders.Target);
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folders.Source, "*.*"))
            {
                string targetFile = Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(file));
                if (File.Exists(targetFile)) File.Delete(targetFile);
                File.Move(file, targetFile);
            }

            foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folders.Source))
            {
                stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));
            }
        }
        Directory.Delete(source, true);
    }
    public class Folders
    {
        public string Source { get; private set; }
        public string Target { get; private set; }

        public Folders(string source, string target)
        {
            Source = source;
            Target = target;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't get a stackoverflow for sub-directories anyway, Windows can handle far fewer sub-directories than .Net can handle recursive calls.

Answer (score 3):

This is copied from [xneurons blog](http://xneuron.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/copy-directory-and-its-content-to-another-directory-in-c/).

```
public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target) {
    // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
    if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
    }

    // Copy each file into it’s new directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles()) {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories()) {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
            target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to recursively search down folders, you just need to create the directories before you copy...

```
// string source, destination; - folder paths 
int pathLen = source.Length;

foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string subPath = dirPath.SubString(pathLen);
    string newpath = Path.Combine(destination, subPath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath );
}

foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string subPath = filePath.SubString(pathLen);
    string newpath = Path.Combine(destination, subPath);
    File.Copy(filePath, newpath);
}
```