# Uninstall existing window service, replace new file and install it again in c#

Tags: c#, windows-services, directory, file-copying, delete-file

I have to uninstall existing window service then copy - replace new files to service location and then install it again.

It works fine when I stop windows application and do it individually.

But, Problem is when do process continuously programmatically,

- Uninstall
- Copy new file
- Install

I got Access Denied error in copy file step. Even I tried to delete file.
The problem is same.

When I delete/Copy-paste manually from directory, it is working.

I used :

Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source path                  , Destination path, true);

and also tried from here :

[ASP.NET C# Copy Directory with SubDirectories with System.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801165/asp-net-c-sharp-copy-directory-with-subdirectories-with-system-io)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I am stopping the service before uninstall, like :

```
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);

var ctlr = new ServiceController();
ctlr.ServiceName = serviceName;
ctlr.Stop();
ctlr.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
result.Success = true;
```

Uninstall :

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u",service path });
```

Replace new files :

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourcepath, DestinationPath, true);
```

Installation:

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { userName, password, servicePath });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ManageInstallerClass` to uninstall the service. It turns out that the `ManageInstallerClass` puts a File Handle lock on the service and you can't delete/replace it until the locking process terminates.

I got around this using the following code:

```
    var s = new ServiceInstaller
    {
        Context = new InstallContext(),
        ServiceName = "<YOUR SERVICE NAME>"
    };
    s.Uninstall(null);
```

After the `ServiceInstaller` finishes you should be able to delete/replace the service file.

To use the `ServiceInstaller` you'll have to include `System.ServiceProcess` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes some time to cleanly stop the service and un-install. Perhaps you may have to wait some time after the un-install and copy new file operation.

Comment: I am stopping the service before uninstalling it. with "WaitForStatus".

Answer (score 0):

Ok , Just type services.msc in command prompt 
It will open list of services currently running on that machine
Then search your window service , Right click and choose options to Stop service.
Once service is stopped you can do whatever you want

```
Visit
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/HJk4xN42AsxpNzCc8vPM?p=preview

Comment: Requirement is : we have to do it programmatically. Actually, we are preparing installer, In that we have to install - uninstall (existing same) services.