# Copy all files from source directory to target directory in C# with file structure

Tags: c#, directory-structure

I want to copy list of files from Source directory to destination directory.

```
Source\a.bat
Source\test\a.bat

Dest\a.bat
Dest\test\a.bat
```

Something I am trying to do

```
public static void ReplicateFile(List<string> files, ref string destinatonFilePath){
      foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                var destDir = Path.Combine(destinatonFilePath, directory);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(destDir))
                    CreateDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(destDir));

                if (fileName != null) File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destDir, fileName), true);
            }
}
```

I am newbie to C#, so apologize for silly mistakes. Any elegant way to do the same?

Since List of `files` contains the below structure `a.bat`, `test\a.bat`.
Any directory function to create the same structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to recursively copy contents in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627504/what-is-the-best-way-to-recursively-copy-contents-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has an example for this:

[How to: Copy Directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to copy all files. Another task hand overs me the list of files to copied. I have checked that before this :)

So I don't have to recursively call sub-dir etc.